# PHP Regular Expressions and CSV Validation

Tags: php, mysql, regex, csv

I am trying to create a CSV Checker which inserts the checked data into a Database and any unsuccessful data added to a .txt file.
I am trying to used regular expressions to validate the data I am inserting, the while loop without any validation works and inserts fine but as soon as regular expressions are used it does not work.

```
<?php
    include_once('connection.php');
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
    $date = date('d/m/y h:i:s a', time());
    $filetxt = "./errors.txt";
    $errors = array();
    $var1 = 5;
    $var2 = 1000;
    $var3 = 10;
    $sql = '';

    if(isset($_POST["Import"]))
    {
        echo $filename=$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]; 
        if($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 0)
        {
            $file = fopen($filename, "r");
            while(($emapData = fgetcsv($file, 10000, ",")) !==FALSE)
            {
                if(isset($_GET['strProductCode']))
                {
                    $emapData[0] =  $conn->real_escape_string(trim($_POST['strProductCode']));

                    if (!preg_match("^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$^", $_POST['strProductCode']))
                    {
                        $errors['strProductCode'];
                    }
                }
                if(isset($_GET['strProductName']))
                {
                    $emapData[1] =  $conn->real_escape_string(trim($_GET['strProductName']));
                    if (!preg_match("^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$^", $_POST['strProductName']))
                    {
                        $errors['strProductName'];
                    }
                }
                if(isset($_GET['strProductDesc']))
                {
                    $emapData[2] =  $conn->real_escape_string(trim($_GET['strProductDesc']));
                    if (!preg_match("^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$^", $_POST['strProductDesc']))
                    {
                        $errors['strProductDesc'];
                    }
                }
                if(isset($_GET['intStock']))
                {           
                    if (!preg_match("^[0-9]", $_POST['intStock']))
                    {
                        $errors['intStock'];
                    }
                }
                if(isset($_GET['intPrice']))
                {
                    if (!preg_match("[0-9]", $_POST['intPrice']))
                    {
                        $errors['intPrice'];
                    }
                }
                if(isset($_GET['dtmDiscontinued'])){
                    if($emapData[6] == preg_match("[a-zA-Z]", $_POST['dtmDiscontinued']))
                    {

                        $emapData[6] = $date;
                        echo $date;
                    }else{
                            $emapData[6] = Null;
                        }
                }
                if(count($errors > 0))
                {
                    // errors 
                    $write = "$emapData[0], $emapData[1], $emapData[2], $emapData[3], $emapData[4], $emapData[5], $emapData[6]\r\n";     
                    file_put_contents($filetxt , $write , FILE_APPEND);

                }else{
                    // insert into Database
                        $sql = "INSERT INTO tblproductdata(strProductCode, strProductName, strProductDesc, intStock, intPrice, dtmAdded, dtmDiscontinued) VALUES('$emapData[0]','$emapData[1]','$emapData[2]','$emapData[3]','$emapData[4]','$date','$emapData[6]')";
                    $res=$conn->query($sql);
                    }

            }
            fclose($file);
            echo "CSV File has successfully been Imported";
            echo "<br>";
            echo "Any errors within the CVS Database are reported here.";
            echo "<br>";
            $fh = fopen($filetxt, 'r');
            $theData = fread($fh, filesize($filetxt));
            fclose($fh);
            echo $theData;

        }else{
            echo "Invalid File: Please Upload a Valid CSV File";    
        }
            header("Location: index.php");
    }
?>
```

My knowledge of PHP is not great but this is my best attempt. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please define "does not work" more closely. At first glance, I see that you often dereference values from the `$errors` array, but do not use these values (like `$errors['intPrice'];`). Are these statements maybe meant to be assignments (like `$errors['intPrice'] = TRUE;` )?

Comment: Well what I mean by "does not work" is the code does not execute any of the  `if(isset($_GET['xxxxxxx']))` which in turn does not add any data to the database and only pushes any data processed by the while loop into the .txt which is meant to store lines from the CSV file which do not meet the validation requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues in your code. Let's start with the regular expressions and your error checking:

1. Some of your expressions are invalid. Note that each expression needs a *delimiting character* at the beginng and ending of the expression. In some of your expressions (like `^[0-9]`) these delimiters are missing. Please also note that using `^` as a delimiter for a regular expression is not a good choice, because the `^` character also has a special meaning in regular expressions.

   This should actually **cause PHP Warnings**. I see that you have `error_reporting` enabled; you should also have a look at your `display_errors` setting.
2. As mentioned in my comment, you do not assign any values to the `$errors` array. The statement `$errors['strProductName']` in itself does not change the array; this means that `$errors` will always be empty. You probably mean to do something like:

   ```
   $errors['strProductName'] = TRUE;
   ```
3. You're actually checking `count($errors > 0)` where you should be checking `count($errors > 0)`. `count($errors > 0)` translates to either `count(TRUE)` or `count(FALSE)` which both equal 1.

Some other notes:

4. Some times, you check for `$_GET['strProductCode']`, but then use `$_POST['strProductCode']`.
5. You do not reset the `$errors` array for each iteration. That means that for each line that you read, the `$errors` variable will still contain the errors from the previous iteration. As a result, the first invalid line will cause all following lines to be recognized as invalid, too.
6. You register an error when one of the parameters is of an invalid format, but not when one of them is not set at all (i.e. when `isset($_POST[...])` is `FALSE`). Each of them should probably be sth. like this:

   ```
   if (isset($_POST['strProductCode'])) {
       $emapData[0] = $conn->real_escape_string(trim($_POST['strProductCode']));
       if (!preg_match("^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$^", $_POST['strProductCode'])) {
           $errors['strProductCode'] = TRUE;
       }
   } else {
       $errors['strProductCode'] = TRUE;
   }
   ```

Comment: Okay so which would be a better choice of delimiter? would `/` be a better and acceptable one? I have already amended my code for 2 & 5. They are straight forward. As to 4. Is it a case of choose either `$_GET` or `$_POST`? or is the statement for the whole of the `if(isset($_GET['strProductCode']))` invalid?

Comment: You can use any character as a delimiter; if you use that character inside the expression, you'll have to escape it, though. `/` seems to be used in most documentation, and it's usually a good choice. Concerning `$_GET` or `$_POST`: This depends on how your form is submitted. If it's submitted using a POST request, use `$_POST`, otherwise use `$_GET`.

Comment: Okay I've taken on board what you have said and it does not come up with any errors now, however the code is still not executing unless I change the `if(isset($_POST['strProductCode']))` to `if(!isset($_POST['strProductCode']))` and then I get error message saying " Undefined index: strProductCode in C:\wamp\www\x-import\index.php on line 31" etc.. Is the strProductCode and the other columns supposed to be predefined at the top?

Comment: Yes, that's probably because you're only triggering an error when a parameter **is set and of invalid format**, but not when a parameter is **not set at all**. I've updated my answer accordingly to address this point.